# Is there a good recent Literature Review on Linear Regression models?

Tags: regression, linear-model

The literature review should include:

- Ordinary least squares (OLS)
- Generalized least squares (GLS)
- Least absolute deviation (LAD)
- Quantile regression
- Least-angle regression
- Ridge regression
- Percentage least squares

among others.

The review should not necessarily include mathematical details of the models. It should focus instead on a classification of the models, in terms of their assumptions, estimation algorithms, robustness, and other relevant characteristics.

Comment: Why not just get a good, up to date regression textbook?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The topics you mention are *too* wide to be part of a single review. What I would suggest is to search on review-style journals, such as:

- Statistical Science: [Example](http://projecteuclid.org/search_result?q.a.title=regression&q.a.author=&q.f.authority=euclid.ss&type=index).
- International Statistical Review: [Example](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/journal/10.1111/(ISSN)1751-5823)

Comment: A few other possibilities:  http://www.hindawi.com/journals/jps/          http://imstat.org/ss/

Answer (score 4):

You are probably better off with a good recent regression textbook such as 
[Berk's (2010) *Statistical Learning from a Regression Perspective*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1441926542).